# React MUI .v5 DatePicker: TextField not updating after selecting date

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've gotten this code straight from the MUI .v5 documentation. After selecting a date from the picker, the Text field does not update to reflect the selected date. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

[Here is an image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFO5h.png)
I expect the part that says Basic example to say 05/30/2022

Comment: Your code works just fine when I test it in sandbox: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-banzai-02y7vu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You're right. I winder what is wrong with my local code